Conflicto de cors con 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
tengo una aplicación de nodejs y de front react, esta aplicación la estoy trabajando en project IDX, la configuración del cors la tengo de la siguiente forma:
backend:
app.use(cors({
   origin: 'https://5173-url-front-idx.dev',
   credentials: true
}));

front:
const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://3000-url-backend-idx.dev',
   withCredentials: true
});

esta configuración funciona sin ningún problema en local, pero en IDX no, cuando veo la consola del navegador me dice que el error es 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', dice esperar un true y recibe un string vacío (' '), lo cual no tiene sentido ya que como se ve en código se le está enviando un true
